# How to process only unique keys from kafkaStreams?

Tags: apache-kafka, group-by, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka

```
Properties streamsConfiguration = this.buildKafkaProperties();
        LOGGER.info("kafka properties for streaming is ::{}", streamsConfiguration);
        StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        KStream<String, LocationChangeEvent> kStream = builder.stream(this.kafkaConfigProperties.getTopicName(), Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), locationChangeEventSerde));
KGroupedStream<String, LocationChangeEvent> grouped = kStream.groupBy((key, value) -> key);
      grouped.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Long.parseLong(String.valueOf(Duration.ofMinutes(2)))));
```

Explanation: I want to remove duplicate Keys from kafka streams.
I have `KafkaStreams<String,LocationChangeEvent> kstreams`...

Example - Suppose I got these events in kafkaStreams

```
{id="1",event1},
{id="2",event2},
{id="3",event3},
{id="1",event3},
{id="2",event3}
```

Now, I want to group them so that no duplicate key exist(id) within given time frame.
output `kafkaStream`:

```
{id="1",event1},
{id="2",event2},
{id="3",event3}
```

duplicate keys are removed from `kafkaStream`.
Tried using `Kstreams.groupByKey()` but it doesn't work for my case.
I don't want count for unique keys. I want my `Kstream` to contain only unique keys and corresponding events.

Comment: Can you please elaborate using a lil bit code so that i can proceed? I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `aggragete` with `suppress` for that. Sample code will be as follow:

```
KGroupedStream<String, LocationChangeEvent> grouped = kStream.groupBy((key, value) -> key);
grouped.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMinutes(2)))
        .aggregate(null, (key, value, agg) -> Optional.ofNullable(agg).orElse(value))
        .suppress(Suppressed.untilWindowCloses(unbounded()))
        .toStream()
        .map((windowedKey, value) -> new KeyValue<>(windowedKey.key(), value));
```

More details regarding suppress you can find [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results)

Comment: If I need the latest event corresponding to a key in particular time frame i.e for above example for "id1" , I need "event3". How can I implement that? please help

Comment: I want to fetch the record with latest timestamp corresponding to key within 10 minute window. Suppose events are {id="1",event1},
{id="2",event2},
{id="3",event8},
{id="1",event3},
{id="2",event4} , then it should give me =>
{id="1",event3},
{id="2",event4},
{id="3",event8},

Comment: If you can rely on ordering, you could do `reduce((agg,value) -> value)` -- if you want to take record timestamps into account, you can access the timestamps via `transformValues()` before the `groupByKey` (you should use `groupByKey` instead of a no-op `groupBy` to avoid an expensive and unnecessary repartitioning) and do `reduce((agg,value) -> value.timestamp >= agg.timestamp ? value : agg)`. After the aggregation you can remove the timestamp again with a `mapValues` step.